# mistake in graduate application

Tags: graduate-admissions

I have submitted an phd application, and I made a made a mistake by instead of setting the degree conferral date to 2023, I did to 2022, can I send them an email they will give me a second chance to correct it?

Comment: It is probably going to be fine if you correct it. It may be obvious already that you made an error, given the date. And, for Fall 2023 admission, it isn't a material error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. As a general rule, apologize and send out corrections as soon as the issue is discovered; do not waste anyone's time. If the issue is more complex and requires substantial work on your part, you may issue a notice first, but it is clearly not applicable here.